# Aviation's forgotten how to sort

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, sorting, beta-sites, specific-site

Observe that [MSO's unanswered by votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) is in the correct order: highest votes at the top.

[Aviation's](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) *was* in the correct order, but now seems to have gone awry:

<sup>Note: Aviation is currently in private beta</sup>

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's .. strange. Looking.

Comment: Apparently they don't care too much for a supersonic civilian aircraft...

Comment: @Jamal It's waiting on a couple more close votes `;)`

Comment: Ah.  Perhaps because it just attracts speculation?

Comment: @Jamal You got it

Comment: Yeah, makes sense.  I'd view it, but I'm not part of the private beta.  Anyway, I hope the website does well!

Comment: @Jamal The site's now in public beta.

Comment: It appears as if this has been fixed.